# Why I'm unable to use mouse to drag and drop and even click in C# browser

Tags: c#, google-blockly

I want to use Google blockly in my C# Window Form. I'm using inbuilt Webbrowser in my application.
Here is Code :

```
   namespace WbView
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser();
                browser.Navigate("https://blockly-demo.appspot.com/static/demos/interpreter/step-execution.html");
                browser.Width = 800;
                browser.Height = 600;
                this.Controls.Add(browser);
            }
        }
    }
```

When I'm running it first time I got Script Error like this
[image]

But After that I changed some Registry entries and it works according to modern browsers

## Registry Entries

[image]

But the Problem is Now I'm unable to use mouse to drag and drop Blocks not even zoom in or zoom out what I can use is just the toolbox to show blocks and nothing else.
[image]

Does anyone faced this type of Problem?
What have I done:

**1.** I have used CefSharp and it was works perfectly. but CefSharp Supports only > .net v4.x.x but I want that my application supports min. .NET v3.5
**I want that my Application support windows 7, 8, 10**

Answer (score 0):

What version of Windows do you need to support? If it's 1803 (this years April update) you can and should use this new/modern webview.
https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2018/05/09/modern-webview-winforms-wpf-apps/

**Programmatically adding WebView**

After installing the NuGet package, you can add the WebView to your application like any other control. The WinForms version of the control is in the Microsoft.Toolkit.Win32.UI.Controls.WinForms namespace.
using Microsoft.Toolkit.Win32.UI.Controls.WinForms;

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
  public Form1()
  {
    InitializeComponent();

    // Initialize WebView and add it to the Window's controls
    var wvc = new WebView();
    ((ISupportInitialize)wvc).BeginInit();
    wvc.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    Controls.Add(wvc);
    ((ISupportInitialize)wvc).EndInit();

    // You can also use the Source property
    wvc.Navigate(new Uri("https://www.microsoft.com"));
}
```

Here is the Nuget: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Toolkit.Win32.UI.Controls/

> Install-Package Microsoft.Toolkit.Win32.UI.Controls -Version 3.0.0

The browser component you are using right now is not good for modern web stuff.

Comment: hey! I'm getting this error Microsoft.Toolkit.Win32.UI.Controls 3.0.0'. You are trying to install this package into a 
project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v3.5', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are 
compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

Comment: Perhaps `install-package geckofx45` then. You need a different modern browser/webview then the old default one.

Comment: I have tried geckofx45 but it is not working as I want. It show pages more terrible ^_^ :P

Comment: cefsharp supports framework  > 4.5.2 but I want my application run at least .net framework 3.5

Comment: 3.5 was released in 2002. 4.5.2 is from May 2014 (also 4 years old) Perhaps move to .Net Core and Standard because you can include the framework in the build. Not being dependent to the installed version.